# Programming STM32F103C using USB

Tags: usb, stm32, flash, bootloader

## What's the Problem?

I created a Custom 'Development/Discovery'-Board and want to program it using USB. I saw in the Datasheet **AN2606** that it is not possible to flash the program via USB.

[image]

## What I tried

A user on this Page told me I need to a flash a **Bootloader** first using USART1. I wathed multiple videos on this topic and up to a certain point every works. *(see following steps)*

### Working steps:

1. Connecting the Board to Power Supply and to USART1 (here via micro-USB, using the **CP2102N** as a USB to UART Bridge)
2. The device manager detects the UART1-Bridge (see picture) as COM[image]
3. Using the **STMFlashLoader** to flash the Bootloader (found on GitHub) [image] 
    also put the Boot0 High, and the Boot1 low. (like mentioned in the Datasheet Pattern1: [image]
4. Getting to the next window (with the traficlight) --> saying Flash size is 64KB.[image]
5. Then choosing the *STM32F1_Med-density_64K* version of the Target
6. Still following the tutorials, I choose *Download to device* and selecting the Download from file the binary-file: **generic_boot20_pc13.bin** (downloaded from GitHub)
7. Its staring downloading and it also finished successfully

[image]

8. Then I click on close

### Nothing works from here on

*I dont know if its on me or if the pc doesnt have all the nessasary tools.*
**What am I doning next?**

1. Turn the Boot0 back to 0 (low or GND)
2. Disconnecting the cable i use for setting the Boot1 pin to GND
3. Then reseting the Board through a *Hard reset* or via reset button

**here is where I relaize something is not working:**

4. Connecting the Board again with the USB cable but on the Power-USB
5. The LED (in Boot0 = 0 Mode) starts blinking like the pc_13 Bootup should do.
6. **But the USB-Device dont get recognize** *(see image below)* [image]

#Does anyone know what I could also do?#

### I also tried following:

- Using the STM32CubeProgrammer
- Uploading a own Programm (where I activate the possibility for the USB to receive data (working) & sending data (not really sure if working (but should do)).

Maybe someone also had a hard time with this. Hope you can help me!

Comment: You did read the bootloader manual how to use it? Does your board have the necessary hardware to support that bootloader, or USB connections?

Comment: @Justme, I looked at the Datasheet AN2606 and didnt find any more specific informations. To receive via USB, I only need an connection to the board via D+/D- I thought?!

Comment: The AN2606 won't be able to tell you if some random bootloader you downloaded from Github will work on your MCU or on your PCB.

Comment: What should I look for? I used the GitHub Bootloader mentioned in all the Tutorials (see [here](https://github.com/rogerclarkmelbourne/STM32duino-bootloader/blob/master/binaries/generic_boot20_pc13.bin))

Comment: How would a random Github bootloader know which frequency crystal your board has? What frequency crystal you have, or do you even use a crystal on your board? Any piece of code must be run on compatible hardware.

Comment: I use HSE and have an 16MHz clock on the board. @Justme, does that mean I have to create my own Bootloader for receiving and transmitting data via USB (like I already mentioned in the Post above?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145150/discussion-between-y-e-quit-and-justme).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have wrong crystal for the bootloader.

You also don't have a pushbutton which the custom bootloader can read to determine if the bootloader should jump to user program or stay in the bootloader and start communicating with USB.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in the discussion chat above with @Paul, it looks like I have to write an own Bootloader for my board specific.

#### Following Steps then need to be followed:

1. Code own Bootloader *(will be added in the future)*
2. Upload the File *(following the working steps in Problem description above)*

--> follow the steps mentioned in the above Problem section.

### other options

Like mentioned by other Users in the comments, it is also possible to use the same Bootloader but to change the settings (for example: *change clock size*, and so on).

--> **if fixed in the near future**, will be later on be added

Comment: No, that is not the only option. You can simply take one that works on your MCU and board as-is, or can be easily configured and recompiled to work on your MCU and board. You don't really have to code anything if you don't want to.